# What options do I have to purchase a play store app for another account?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, in-app-purchase

Recently my wife gave birth to our son and I purchased the [tinycam pro app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alexvas.dvr.pro&hl=pt_BR) to use with my d-link DCS-932L as a baby monitor.

After some tests I was satisfied with the results and decided to buy the app for my wife's google account, so she can monitor our child with her own phone. It was a surprise when I found that google provides no simple way to achieve such a simple task.

My wife has no international credit card, and even if she did I would be reluctant to associate her google account with one, since she's very careless regarding account/password security

What options do I have to install the app on my wife's phone without adding credit card information to her account?

Comment: I was going to suggest have her create an independent PayPal account and use Google's Pay with PayPal, but I guess that isn't available in Brazil either.

Comment: Additional clarification: are both or either of your devices rooted?

Comment: Both are rooted

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to buy some [Google Play credit](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3422734?hl=en&ref_topic=3421698) you enter the code you buy into your wife's play store, and you can use that balance to buy apps

Comment: I'm in Brazil which is not listed in the available countries, so I guess this is not an option for me

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to add your Google Account to her phone, disable all syncing (Gmail, Calendar, Contacts, etc.), and then install the app from the Play store from your account. I did this with my wife's phone so that I could use some apps that I had purchased but on her phone. Google Play currently has "no data move functionality available" <sup>[source](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/58582?hl=en)</sup> so transferring purchases is not an option.

Comment: That's not an option for me for the same reason I don't want to add credit card info to her account: I'm a computer security geek and she's the opposite of it. For example, it wouldn't surprise me if she installed spyware on her phone that would steal information from both our accounts

Answer (score 0):

If the device that already has the app installed is rooted, you can pull the `.apk` file. This can be achieved a few different ways:

- using a specialized app (such as [AppMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager) or [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup))
- via `adb pull` if the ADB daemon runs in root-mode (it usually doesn't, but that can be achieved using [adbd Insecure](http://www.appbrain.com/app/%5Broot%5D-adbd-insecure/eu.chainfire.adbd)) <sup>[src](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/53904/37474)</sup>
- Using a file explorer and granting it root access, and searching for the apk in your `/data/` partition

DISCLAIMER: As long as you pull these files "for backup" but keep them to yourself, there shouldn't be any legal risks. Any other use may constitute [warez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warez). Using this method to install the .apk file to another device is at your own will and risk.

Comment: I have a root explorer and can send the apk via Bluetooth, but what about license checks?

Comment: Because of how this is verified differently (ie. An additional `unlocker.apk`, adding LicensingPermissions only, or a custom ServerManagedPolicy), you will just need to try for yourself. Given that you've refused all other methods, your choices are already limited.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is available from Amazon's app store you can buy the app on Amazon from a PC and then install the App on the phone from Amazon's app store app.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, there is no gift system in google play like Steam has. This app has a free version limited to 4 simultaneous cameras and 30 secs audio, try that one. If she really needs the full vesion, you can register your pay method, but each time you CHANGE one payment method to your google's account they discount 1,5 USD from you credit card so take that in count.

Answer (score -1):

There are various ways through which you could buy a premium for other users you wish

- You can buy some credit through the Google Play Gift Card as John has suggested although its availability is limited (i.e. If Google Play gift cards are not supported in their area then it would be waste of buying the credit).
- Some applications also have the "pay for other's" feature like in whatsapp. Through this if both the users are using and you wish to make another user a premium then you can go in for this option. This option is normally available under the settings.

  - Good part - this feature is not geographically limited.
  - Bad part - both the users need to use this software.
- Download [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) on any desktop or laptop. Login with the other person's account (your wife's Gmail account). Select the app from my apps and you can purchase it.

  - Good part - You don't at all require any android operating device. You can download it on any windows operating System.(correct me if I am wrong on this )
  - Bad part - Although Blue Stacks works perfectly for almost all the apps some applications may not work properly(depending on your machine's hardware limitations) and does not support any OS other then Windows
  - *Update*:-here when A has downloaded the blue stacks he will install
    the tiny cam app for which he has to purchase it. As A has signed in
    using his wife's account all the purchases will be made in the name
    of the account holder i.e. his wife not on A so on doing so
    automatically the purchase is made on the wife's email id. Later when
    his wife will open the play store the application will be
    automatically installed/updated as a premium.

Comment: I couldn't understand what BlueStacks is about by reading the front page you linked. Can you elaborate?

Comment: BlueStacks is an android emulator - you can install and run android apps on a windows machine.

Comment: But how will TinyCam appear in his wife's My Apps page if she didn't even purchase it?

Comment: @aure Please don't be foolish  here I have clearly mentioned that using blue stacks you can use Android apps on your desktop machine which means that you can download the application on behalf of your wife. Later when your wife opens the play store the applications are updated /synchronised automatically.

Comment: in short whatever apps you have installed on your desktop through bluestacks software will later be displayed for you to install it/ gets updated automatically.

Comment: @ThiadodeArruda I have  updated the answer for a clear understanding  plz check it

Comment: I still cant understand how that will help me. Even if I add her account to a BlueStacks VM, I would still need to associate credit card information(with her acct) in order to purchase, right?

Comment: @ThiadodeArruda no not all after adding you can use a gift card from the retailer and use it for your app